# Regex match a pattern occurring multiple times in a string

Tags: regex, unix, grep

Using `grep`in Ubuntu, I am trying to regex match a pattern that is repeated multiple times in a line.

Example:
`0:0, 80:3, 443:0, 8883:0, 9000:0, 9001:0,`

The regex I tried is -

`([0-9]+:[0-9]+, )+`

But it only matches upto -

`0:0, 80:3, 443:0, 8883:0, 9000:0,`

I would want it to match the complete line. Also, I'd appreciate if the regex will check if there is a presence of `80` and `443` in the matched string.

**Expectation -**

The following lines should be matched -

```
0:0, 80:3, 443:0, 8883:0, 9000:0, 9001:0,
0:0, 80:0, 443:1, 8883:0, 9000:0, 9001:0,
0:0, 80:0, 443:0, 8883:0, 9000:0, 9001:0,
0:0, 80:3, 443:1, 8883:0, 9000:0, 9001:0,
```

and the ones below should **not** be matched -

```
0:0, 443:0, 8883:0, 9000:0, 9001:0,
0:0, 80:0, 8883:0, 9000:0, 9001:0,
0:0, 8883:0, 9000:0, 9001:0,
```

Comment: Please add your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: It's not matching the last term because there's no space on the end of your input string, but your regex requires one.  If the spaces are optional, you could just use " *" instead of " " in the regex.  If not, then you need to match "either space or end of line", which would be "( |$)" instead of the " ", or, if you're going to examine the match results and don't want to capture the spaces, you can use a non-capturing group, "(?: |$)".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
^[0-9]+:[0-9]+, 80:[0-9]+, 443:[0-9]+(, [0-9]+:[0-9]+)+,$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ty8JW7/1).

Also, consider the `awk` solution like

```sh
awk '/^[0-9]+:[0-9]+(, [0-9]+:[0-9]+)+,$/ && /80/ && /443/' file
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/pD2W9J):

```sh
#!/bin/bash
s='0:0, 80:3, 443:0, 8883:0, 9000:0, 9001:0,
0:0, 80:0, 443:1, 8883:0, 9000:0, 9001:0,
0:0, 80:0, 443:0, 8883:0, 9000:0, 9001:0,
0:0, 80:3, 443:1, 8883:0, 9000:0, 9001:0,
0:0, 443:0, 8883:0, 9000:0, 9001:0,
0:0, 80:0, 8883:0, 9000:0, 9001:0,
0:0, 8883:0, 9000:0, 9001:0,'
awk '/^[0-9]+:[0-9]+(, [0-9]+:[0-9]+)+,$/ && /80/ && /443/' <<< "$s"
```

Output:

```
0:0, 80:3, 443:0, 8883:0, 9000:0, 9001:0,
0:0, 80:0, 443:1, 8883:0, 9000:0, 9001:0,
0:0, 80:0, 443:0, 8883:0, 9000:0, 9001:0,
0:0, 80:3, 443:1, 8883:0, 9000:0, 9001:0,
```

Comment: Thanks Wiktor - Can the regex be changed so that the lines with `80:3, 443:0,` can be matched irrespective of their positions? Eg. Both `0:0, 80:0, 443:1, 8883:0,` and `0:0, 443:1, 80:0, 8883:0,` are matched.

Comment: @Ira This is what my `awk` does, see `awk '/^[0-9]+:[0-9]+(, [0-9]+:[0-9]+)+,$/ && /80/ && /443/' file`

Answer (score 2):

Here is more robust `awk` pattern match, which is as per your shown samples, written and tested in GNU `awk`, should work in any `awk`. Simple explanation of `awk` code would be: `awk` works on method of `condition/regexp` then `action`, so I am mentioning `condition/regexp` here with NO action so if regexp is TRUE(matched) then by default printing of line will happen.

`awk '/^0:[0-9],[[:space:]]+80:[0-9],[[:space:]]+443:[0-9],[[:space:]]+8883:[0-9](,[[:space:]]+9[0-9]{3}:[0-9]){2},$/'  Input_file`

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above regex.

```
^0:[0-9],[[:space:]]+             ##From starting of line matching 0 followed by colon followed by comma, followed y 0 OR 1 occurrences of space(s).
80:[0-9],[[:space:]]+             ##Above regex is followed by 80 colon any digit comma and space(s).
443:[0-9],[[:space:]]+            ##Above is followed by 443 colon digit comma and space(s).
8883:[0-9]                        ##Above is followed by 8883 followed by colon followed by any digit.
(,[[:space:]]+9[0-9]{3}:[0-9]){2} ##matching comma space(s) followed by 9 which is followed by 3 digits and this whole match 2 times(to match last 2 9000 etc values).
,$                                ##Matching comma at the end of line here.
```